# What is the best datatype to store a list of words and lines in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I am making a small program that reads a text file and stores it in the memory. It then lets the user add another line to the file, replace a line, add another word at a specific line etc...

At the end the user can save the content from the memory back to the file.
I did the same program in Python and used a multidimensional array, so each element in the array was an array of words.
This made it really easy to access a specific word at a specific line to be replaced with something else

Now I am trying to do the same thing with C and getting confused. After a little bit of messing around I am leaning more towards having a structure that has char words[]. This way I can delete a specific line by just dereferencing the NextNode from the previous to next.

I have two questions tho:
1. Is this a good way of accomplishing my goal?
2. How do I make a linked list with a FIXED size (e.g. no use of malloc). For example if I want to have a maximum 10 lines, how do I just make ten nodes and avoid malloc?

Comment: Post some code. The description is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Why you want Fixed size?

It is Easy to make a linked list with a FIXED size (e.g no use of malloc), It is called as an array of Structure :)

If you can create a structure, say "node" :

```
#define MAXLEN   100
typedef struct node
{
  int nLinenum;
  char Data[MAXLEN];

};
```

You can write:

```
node static_linked_list[10];
```

But you need to write a bit complex code to remove perticular node. It is not simple as compared to removing node from a linked list(with malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simplest approach: (Listing only structure definitions).

```
    struct word {
        char m_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    };

    struct line {
        struct word[MAX_WORDS_PER_LINE];
    };

    struct _node {
        struct line m_line;
        struct _node *next;
    };
```

Using fixed size DS will not serve your purpose.
At a later point you should also replace arrays (m_word & line->word) with a linklist.

Comment: I don't understand what the struct word is for? You're not using it in _node?

Comment: a line is a collection of words. node.m_line.word[5] will provide the 6th word in the particular line.